# Partial specialization with more template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Is a partial specialization allowed to have more template parameters than the primary template? My understanding was that the a partial specialization must have either lesser or the same number of template parameters as the primary template.

I am reading C++ Templates (2nd Edition) and in that it is mentioned on Section 5.4 (Page 72) that

```
template <typename T, std::size_t SZ>
struct MyClass<T[SZ]>{
    static void print(){}
};
```

and

```
template <typename T, std::size_t SZ>
struct MyClass<T (&)[SZ]>{
    static void print(){}
};
```

are both partial specializations of the primary template

```
template <typename T>
struct MyClass;
```

The accompanying code works fine. But is this correct? Can a partial specialization have more template parameters than the primary template?

Edit - This question has been marked a duplicate of another question but the answers there are unrelated to the question here. The Question here is reagarding the number of template parameters and the comments and quick rereading of the standard clarified the answer for me.

Comment: What do you mean by more parameters ? in both case it is `MyClass<T1>` even if `T1` need several parameter to specify it. You can't have `MyClass<T1, T2>`

Comment: @Jarod42 - Angew's answer below seems to contradict your statement

Comment: @AshishDaggubatti: He doesn't contradict, `std::function<T1>` and not `std::function<T1, T2>`. (with `T1` = `R(A...)`).

Comment: I do understand it is just one type....as in you pass in an array which is represented by 2 template parameters....but in the standard, partial specialization is referred to as something where you customize a template by specifying only a subset of the template parameters which means the number of template parameters must not increase and hence the question

Comment: Where it's referred as such? You specialize/customize declared template parameters, but nothing says that you can't specialize them specifically with even more parameters.

Comment: @AshishDaggubatti That is not the way the standard defines partial specializations, it's much broader: "A partial specialization of a class template provides an alternative definition of the template that is used instead of the primary definition when the arguments in a specialization match those given in the partial specialization."

Comment: Ok my misunderstanding. On rereading the section on partial specialization - the following stood out:

This is done by matching the template arguments of the class template specialization with the template argument lists of the partial specializations.

If no matches are found, the instantiation is generated from the primary template.

A partial specialization matches a given actual template argument list if the template arguments of the partial specialization can be deduced from the actual template argument list

Comment: All of which apply to the case above...so basically it doesnt matter if the partial specialization has more parameters...as long as the template arguments supplied match either a partial specialization (or a more specialized one in case of many matches) or it matches a primary template then the code would work fine....i can understand Jarod42's statement now when he said T = R(A...) or T = T1[SZ]....so primary template will still continue to match for these arguments if the partial specialization were skipped which in effect means that examples above only match in special cases unlike pri tmpl

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, a partial specialisation can indeed have more template parameters than the primary template. A typical example of this use is `std::function`:

```
template <class T>
struct function;

template <class R, class... A>
struct function<R (A...)>
{
  // std::function as we know it
};
```

Comment: Why does std::function even need this useless base version?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe What exactly do you mean? Why it needs the primary template? That is so that you can write `std::function<int(double, char)>` (with a *single* type parameter), and not e.g. `std::function<int, double, char>`.

Comment: Thank you, this is somewhat eye-opening. I never realized template argument deduction works like this.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe This is more about partial template specialisation matching than about argument deduction per se (although deduction certainly plays a role in the matching).